# How to align timestamps from two Datasets in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got the following problem, while developing an Apache Spark Application. I have two Datasets (D1 and D2) from a Postgresql Database, that I would like to process using Apache Spark. Both contain a column (ts) with timestamps from the same period. I would like to join D2 with the largest timestamp from D1 that is smaller or equal. It might look like:

```
 D1      D2                DJOIN 
|ts|    |ts|             |D1.ts|D2.ts|
----    ----             -------------
| 1|    | 1|             |   1 |   1 |
| 3|    | 2|             |   1 |   2 |
| 5|    | 3|             |   3 |   3 |
| 7|    | 4|             |   3 |   4 |
|11|    | 5|             |   5 |   5 |
|13|    | 6|             |   5 |   6 |
        | 7| = join =>   |   7 |   7 |
        | 8|             |   7 |   8 |
        | 9|             |   7 |   9 |
        |10|             |   7 |  10 |
        |11|             |  11 |  11 |
        |12|             |  11 |  12 |
        |13|             |  13 |  13 |
        |14|             |  13 |  14 |
```

In SQL I can simply write something like:

```
SELECT D1.ts, D2.ts
FROM D1, D2
WHERE D1.ts = (SELECT max(D1.ts)
               FROM D1
               WHERE D1.ts <= D2.ts);
```

There is the possibility for nested `SELECT` queries in Spark Datasets but unfortunately they support only equality `=` and no `<=`. I am a beginner in Spark and currently I am stuck here. Is there someone more knowledgable with a good idea on how to solve that issue?